# How to login this website with python requests?

Tags: python, asp.net

I want to login to this website: https://neptun1.semmelweis.hu/hallgato2/login.aspx
I studied the outgoing requests with Firefox Tamper Data addon.
That is whats going on after I hit the login buton(Bejelentkezés).
url:

`/hallgato2/login.aspx/GetMaxTryNumber
parameter name:
parameter value:
url:/hallgato2/login.aspx/CheckLoginEnable
parametername:"user":"username","pwd":"password","UserLogin":null,"GUID":null}
parameter value:blank
url:/hallgato2/Login.aspx/SavePopupState
parameter name:{"state":"hidden","PopupID":"upLoginWait_popupLoginWait"}
parameter value:blank`

And finally this page what i want to reach: https://neptun1.semmelweis.hu/hallgato2/main.aspx

My code :

```
import requests
x="""{"user":"username goes here","pwd":"password goes here","UserLogin":null,"GUID":null}""" 
payload={x:""}

url="https://neptun1.semmelweis.hu/hallgato2/login.aspx/CheckLoginEnable"
r=requests.post(url,data=payload,verify=False)#Bad SSl certifacate 
cookie=r.cookies

url="https://neptun1.semmelweis.hu/hallgato2/main.aspx"
r1=requests.get(url,cookies=cookie,verify=False)
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is i cant access to the https://neptun1.semmelweis.hu/hallgato2/main.aspx when i save r1.text into a text file and i open it in a webbrowser i only see the login page instead of the page what a normally logged user shoud see.

Comment: What do you see in the response to `CheckLoginEnable`? It should be a `json` object and will contain an error message that will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for your suggenstion the server waited for json post message and my code was sending normal/html so i eddited my code:    payload={"user":"username","pwd":"pass","UserLogin":"null",   "GUID":"null"   
             }
             url="https://neptun1.semmelweis.hu/hallgato2/login.aspx/CheckLoginEnable"
             r=s.post(url,json=payload,verify=False,headers=header)

Comment: And now the r.json() says that Succesful login but i still get the login page when i try to access to the main.aspx
What i discovered is that when i login in the browser i have asxpauth and ASP.NET_SessionId cookie after the login
when i try to login with my script i have got ASP.NET_SessionId only.